# Is there a way to build a snappy pakage from a unstable repo like the arch repo or DebianUnstable repo

Tags: package-management, repository, snap

I am wondering if you can truly get new package versions with snappy?
Maybe something like running a chroot of DebianUnstable and using [deb2snap](https://github.com/mikix/deb2snap) to build snappys? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes-- deb2snap was superannuated long ago by snapcraft. You can use it to build snaps directly from upstream sources, or by utilizing debs. No chroot needed! A good walkthrough is [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/).